# Rails adding a row to a csv that only has headers and no data removes the headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-3

I am reading a CSV file from a CDN and adding data to it then writing it back to a CDN for this reason I can't use append file.

I am also reordering the file which is why I have to turn it back into a CSV::Table

This code is a slimed down version of what I have but the problem is still replicated.

```
class SomeForm::Form
  class << self

    def add
      data = CSV.parse(open(csv_file_url).read, headers: true)
      data << ['david', 'smith'] # this will be dynamic
      # data = data.sort_by { |row| [row['Firstname'], row['Lastname']] }
      write_csv_file(CSV::Table.new(data).to_csv)
    end


    def csv_file_url
      #somecode to get the file_url
    end

    def write_csv_file(data)
      #somecode to write the file to the cdn
    end
  end
end
```

CSV file

```
Firstname,Lastname
```

So if I run SomeForm::Form.add with the csv file as above it outputs (removing the headers)

```
,
David,smith
```

However if the CSV file has at least one record in eg

```
Firstname,Lastname
Steve,Cougan
```

and run the code it adds the new record as expected

```
Firstname,Lastname
Steve,Cougan
david,smith
```

I would like to get this to work with csv with data in and csv with just the headers in.

As a aside this is for a rails3 project, though the above is replicatable in rails 5 as well

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I simplified the script but I can't really reproduce your issue.

```rb
data = CSV.parse("Firstname,Lastname", headers: true)
data << ['david', 'smith'] # this will be dynamic
data = data.sort_by { |row| [row['Firstname'], row['Lastname']] }
puts CSV::Table.new(data).to_csv

# Firstname,Lastname
# david,smith
```

However, if you still experience an issue I believe it might be the sorting. The `CSV::Table` class is an enumerable but only iterates over the CSV rows without the headers (except in `col` mode) so that means your sorting might just return an array of arrays without the header. When you now initialize the new `CSV::Table` it will by default use the first row as the headers. Please note that you can access and set the headers as well like this.

```rb
data = CSV.parse("Firstname,Lastname", headers: true)
headers = data.headers

data << ['david', 'smith'] # this will be dynamic
data = data.sort_by { |row| [row['Firstname'], row['Lastname']] }

puts CSV::Table.new(data, headers: headers).to_csv
```

Here are the links to the implementation:

- https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/lib/csv/table.rb#L31-L43
- https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/lib/csv/table.rb#L334-L338

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research following on from Chrisians answer.

And think this may be the problem https://github.com/ruby/csv/issues/75